# PDW System Views Missing from Master Database

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

System views such as sys.pdw_table_distribution_properties are missing from the master database.  The database which I created when I created my instance of SQL Data Warehouse has these views.  Why are these views not included with the master db?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Both SQL Data Warehouse and SQL Database can be deployed on a logical server (SQL Server). The logical SQL Server holds the master database and contains information only about the server. For example, databases on the server in sys.databases.

The sys.pdw_table_distribution_properties DMV is specific to SQL Data Warehouse and will only be available when connected to a SQL Data Warehouse database.

Comment: Thank you.  This article was also useful for understanding the master database on SQL Data Warehouse.  [Managing Databases and Logins in Azure SQL Database](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-manage-logins/)